# GulpSequence is not working, execute only first task

Tags: angular, gulp

i have two angular projects, we build application using gulp

We are using GulpSequence to build one by one. but its execute only one task

The below code we are tried,

```
gulp.task('angular_project_one', function (cb) {
    exec('cd modules/project_one && npm install && ng build --deployUrl=modules/project_one /', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        gulp.src(['modules/project_one /dist/**/*'], {
        }).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    });
});


gulp.task('angular_project_two', function (cb) {
    exec('cd modules/project_two && npm install && ng build --deployUrl=modules/dist/project_two/', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        gulp.src(['modules/project_two/dist/**/*'], {
        }).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    });
});

gulp.task('angular_build', gulpSequence('angular_project_one', 'angular_project_two')(function (err) {
    console.log("build",err)
  }))
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `gulpSequence` probably doesn't know that first task has finished.  A `return` statement or call your `cb()` at the end might do it.

Comment: Can you please add some examples ??

Comment: @Mark Thanks a lot it works for me after adding return statement